# http post from server to other with node js promises

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, post, http-post

I want to post from server consider as proxy to another server with promises. I wrote this code but it does not work, I think the manner with connect with two servers is true:

```
function test(req, res) {
    var pro = getPromiseP();
    pro.then(function(data) {
         res.send(data);
    }).catch(function(err) {
        console.log(err);
    })
}
function getPromiseP(){
    var options = {
        host: 'localhost',
        port: 3000,
        path: '/btest',
        method:'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body:{
          'id':1,
          'name':'name4'
        }
    };
    var promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        var req = http.request(options,function(res) {
            res.on('data', function(body) {
                var data = '';
                data += body;
                resolve(data);
                return;
            });
        });
        req.on('error', function(e) {
            console.log('problem with request: ' + e.message);
            reject(e);
        });
    });
    return promise;
}
```

Comment: How can I help you, when I cannot reproduce your testcase? What servers did you connect? What errors did you get?

Comment: i try it in postman but i didnt get any result or error i dont know where is my error?
as ur know its right way to post from server to server??

Comment: but I can not try your code with your localhost, dude - what proxy do you use I wonder

Comment: this is first time to me to dealing with connect between two servers, i mean post from server to server

Comment: i see this in postman json Unexpected ' '

Comment: what server do you have at localhost:3000 ?